# Best practice: Include Javascript and CSS in asp.net solution or not?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

My site only uses .aspx for a few pages.  The .aspx pages and regular HTML pages would use the same style sheets and Javascript/Jquery.  Would it make better sense to refer to those files (css/js) outside of my solution, or is it better practice to import them into my solution and refer to those files in my solution?

Does it matter? Are there any speed advantages (page loading) in including CSS and JS files in my solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't a speed loading advantage unless your (CSS, js) resources take advantage of the browser cache and a CDN. The practical answer depends on how many projects rely on a (css, js) resource. Is it the same for all your projects? Will each have significant edits? How are you handling version control and deployment? The trade-off is ease of development for a single project versus a group of projects. No one can really answer this for you.

Comment: Actually you kind of answered my question.  Thanks Jasen!